# Jackson deserialize json string but bean missing json string's property/key

Tags: java, json, jackson

When I used Jackson to deserialize the json string ,i often don't want to create all the bean class's properties, and also I just need some json string's field ,other field i don't need. So i often just write some properties in my java class bean which i needed . but when Jackson parsed it it will return as null for the bean field.

1.The java bean class is: `GistObject` is:

```
public class GistObject {
   private String id;
}
```

2. The jackson Main class code is:

   ```
     String json =
           "    {\n" +
           "        \"url\": \"https://api.github.com/gists/e69fd9f9ef85eb3f30a3b93d2cc9b9b3\",\n" +
           "        \"forks_url\": \"https://api.github.com/gists/e69fd9f9ef85eb3f30a3b93d2cc9b9b3/forks\",\n" +
           "        \"commits_url\": \"https://api.github.com/gists/e69fd9f9ef85eb3f30a3b93d2cc9b9b3/commits\",\n" +
           "        \"id\": \"e69fd9f9ef85eb3f30a3b93d2cc9b9b3\",\n" +
           "        \"git_pull_url\": \"https://gist.github.com/e69fd9f9ef85eb3f30a3b93d2cc9b9b3.git\",\n" +
           "        \"git_push_url\": \"https://gist.github.com/e69fd9f9ef85eb3f30a3b93d2cc9b9b3.git\",\n" +
           "        \"html_url\": \"https://gist.github.com/e69fd9f9ef85eb3f30a3b93d2cc9b9b3\",\n" +
           "        \"files\": {\n" +
           "            \"sample template\": {\n" +
           "                \"filename\": \"sample template\",\n" +
           "                \"type\": \"text/plain\",\n" +
           "                \"language\": null,\n" +
           "                \"raw_url\": \"https://gist.githubusercontent.com/becauseqa-walter/e69fd9f9ef85eb3f30a3b93d2cc9b9b3/raw/a85b555ce30da1f13aa3b7db3a2756bd64462278/sample%20template\",\n" +
           "                \"size\": 877\n" +
           "            }\n" +
           "        },\n" +
           "        \"public\": false,\n" +
           "        \"created_at\": \"2017-05-16T13:28:44Z\",\n" +
           "        \"updated_at\": \"2017-05-16T13:28:44Z\",\n" +
           "        \"description\": \"\",\n" +
           "        \"comments\": 0,\n" +
           "        \"user\": null,\n" +
           "        \"comments_url\": \"https://api.github.com/gists/e69fd9f9ef85eb3f30a3b93d2cc9b9b3/comments\",\n" +
           "        \"owner\": {\n" +
           "            \"login\": \"becauseqa-walter\",\n" +
           "            \"id\": 5029046,\n" +
           "            \"avatar_url\": \"https://avatars1.githubusercontent.com/u/5029046?v=3\",\n" +
           "            \"gravatar_id\": \"\",\n" +
           "            \"url\": \"https://api.github.com/users/becauseqa-walter\",\n" +
           "            \"html_url\": \"https://github.com/becauseqa-walter\",\n" +
           "            \"followers_url\": \"https://api.github.com/users/becauseqa-walter/followers\",\n" +
           "            \"following_url\": \"https://api.github.com/users/becauseqa-walter/following{/other_user}\",\n" +
           "            \"gists_url\": \"https://api.github.com/users/becauseqa-walter/gists{/gist_id}\",\n" +
           "            \"starred_url\": \"https://api.github.com/users/becauseqa-walter/starred{/owner}{/repo}\",\n" +
           "            \"subscriptions_url\": \"https://api.github.com/users/becauseqa-walter/subscriptions\",\n" +
           "            \"organizations_url\": \"https://api.github.com/users/becauseqa-walter/orgs\",\n" +
           "            \"repos_url\": \"https://api.github.com/users/becauseqa-walter/repos\",\n" +
           "            \"events_url\": \"https://api.github.com/users/becauseqa-walter/events{/privacy}\",\n" +
           "            \"received_events_url\": \"https://api.github.com/users/becauseqa-walter/received_events\",\n" +
           "            \"type\": \"User\",\n" +
           "            \"site_admin\": false\n" +
           "        },\n" +
           "        \"truncated\": false\n" +
           "    }";
   ObjectMapper mapper=      new ObjectMapper();
   mapper.setSerializationInclusion(JsonInclude.Include.NON_NULL);
   mapper.configure(DeserializationFeature.FAIL_ON_UNKNOWN_PROPERTIES, false);
   GistObject gistObject =mapper.readValue(json, GistObject.class);
   ```

Then the returned `GistObject` with field `id` is `null`, not expected `e69fd9f9ef85eb3f30a3b93d2cc9b9b3`.
So SOmeone know how to deserialize the json string to java bean without writing all the json string's fields in my java bean class. 
thanks for your response!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add a setter for your property id into your data class like that:

```
public static class GistObject {
    private String id;

    public void setId(String id) { this.id = id; }
}
```

Or you can use the JsonProperty annotation:

```
public static class GistObject {
    @JsonProperty
    private String id;
}
```

Comment: Thanks @Prim ,it's my fault. I had forgot te setter/getter .